# Values input in widget do not update

Tags: python, widget

I am trying to change values in a loop under certains conditions, but the value of the selector does not change and remains the default value. What is the easiest way around this?

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
defaultvalue=[1]
selector = widgets.SelectMultiple(value = defaultvalue,
    options=list,)

for i in range (0,10):
    display(selector)
    input('select from list and press any key to continue')
    print(selector.value)
```

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: `widgets` is undefined.

Comment: import ipywidgets as widgets